# Query posts and return XML

Tags: posts, wp-query, xml

Here is the short and sweet of what I am hoping to do. I would like to have a way for external websites to query mine using a game title and they would get an XML back that contains the text of the review, the score, and some images (this XML should be customizable in order to add/remove elements from it). This seems like it should be easy enough, but my OVERLY limited knowledge of PHP and Wordpress are making this very complicated.

Comment: Does it have to be XML? [JSON](http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/) is the most common form and JetPack enables it. I've never used, though. Oh, maybe sweet, maybe easy, but you could use a [bit of research](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=rest+api+json) ;)

Comment: Wordpress also has an XML-RPC API, http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API